# Prevent div wrapper on tr from being ejected

Tags: html, html-table

Given the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <div>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

When it is rendered, the div gets moved out like so:

```
<div>
</div>
<table>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can only add a `div` to a table if it's in a data cell (`<td><div></div></td>`)

Chris Coyier has a nice post on this: https://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with that div?  Can you use tbody instead?

Comment: You can't prevent it because you're trying to create invalid HTML and the browser is being nice and trying to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the first example is invalid html. You can use a `<tbody>` instead of the `<div>` however.

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` element is not allowed directly within a `<table>` element. Only table related elements are allowed (`<tr>` `<thead>`...).

There's no way to "make this work". Read the HTML specification and form a valid document.

Answer (score 1):

div tag cannot be inside the table like this.

```
<table>
    <div>
    <tr><td></tr></td>
    </div>
    </table>
```

You can put it inside the td like this.

```
<table>
  <tr><td><div></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For reference, see [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).